# class design for for a dynamic GetHash function

Tags: oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern, solid-principles

I have the requirement to calculate an internal hashcode of instances of several types (some types are derived from each other). Two aspects are dynamic here and can vary **independently**. Only the client that requests the hash knows what hash algorithm is to be used and what properties are to be included.

1. The actual algorithm that is used
   for the hash caluctation can change.
2. What members for each type should be take into account for the hash calculation can change.

How would you design your types around these requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some guidelines for GetHashCode() from Eric Lippert.

http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

An excerpt:
Rule: the integer returned by GetHashCode must never change while the object is contained in a data structure that depends on the hash code remaining stable

It is permissible, though dangerous, to make an object whose hash code value can mutate as the fields of the object mutate. If you have such an object and you put it in a hash table then the code which mutates the object and the code which maintains the hash table are required to have some agreed-upon protocol that ensures that the object is not mutated while it is in the hash table. What that protocol looks like is up to you.

In short, if the algorithm for generating the hash code can change, then you need to make sure that it doesn't change while the object is in your collection.

Comment: The focus of my question is not on GetHashCode (this is just an example infact). It is more on the class design propblem when I have to responsibilities in this that are subject to change. I have modified my question and removed the .NET tag to stress this.

Answer (score 0):

First, require all "hashable" objects to implement the same interface, with one method: `getHash()`.

Second, introduce an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) instantiating hash [Strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Example (Java 1.6):

```
public class Foo implements Hashable {
  private String field;
  @Override
  public String getHash() {
    HashFactory.INSTANCE.getMD5Strategy().hash(this.field);
  }
}
```

Proper encapsulation of decision making inside your objects, and an effective decoupling of strategies and objects.

Comment: How do I encapsulate the decision making wich fields are to be included for the hash. The object can not know and the hash strategy can not know. Only the client that wants to actually get the hash knows what the hash is for (i.e. what algorithm to use and what fields are to be included). I updated and clarified my question.

Comment: I think the two independent aspects of the hash calculation must be injected on the fly when the hash is requested by the client.